# C# custom text preposition format

Tags: c#, string, text, position

i need to make a text like the following picture
[image]

and then i make the string text like this

```
string teksnya = "Payment Statement\nSudah " + metode + " Ke Rekening " + RekeningRekber + " MONEX BANK a.n IMANULLAH\n » Harga Barang/Jasa " + hargabarang + " Jasa " + lintascabank+" \n » Total biaya transfer : " + totalpembayaran + " \n » Untuk Pembelian : " + pembelian + " \n » Keterangan Barang/Jasa : " + keterangan + " \n » ID KASKUS Pembeli : " + idbuyer + " \t Email pembeli : " + emailbuyer + " \n » Hp Pembeli : " + nomorhandphonebuyer + " \n ======================================================== \n » BANK Penjual : " + bankseller + " \n » ID KASKUS Penjual : " + idseller + " \n » Email Penjual : " + emailseller + " \t No Hp : " + nomorhandphoneseller + " \n »link thread : " + linklapak + " \n \n Mohon MONEX BANK segera Teruskan Konfirmasi ini ke Penjual, Untuk memproses Barang/Jasa sesuai kesepakatan";
```

why does the result is different from the picture ? why does the `\n` is not working ? 
here is the result
[image]

and when i copy-paste them on notepad, the text position still different from the first picture. please help how to make the text displayed exactly the same as the first picture.

thanks !

update :

here is my current string

```
   string teksnya = "Payment Statement{0}Sudah " + metode + " Ke Rekening " + RekeningRekber + " MONEX BANK a.n IMANULLAH{0} » Harga Barang/Jasa " + hargabarang + " Jasa " + lintascabank + " {0} » Total biaya transfer : " + totalpembayaran + " {0} » Untuk Pembelian : " + pembelian + " {0} » Keterangan Barang/Jasa : " + keterangan + " {0} » ID KASKUS Pembeli : " + idbuyer + " \t Email pembeli : " + emailbuyer + " {0} » Hp Pembeli : " + nomorhandphonebuyer + " {0} ======================================================== {0} » BANK Penjual : " + bankseller + " {0} » ID KASKUS Penjual : " + idseller + " {0} » Email Penjual : " + emailseller + " \t No Hp : " + nomorhandphoneseller + " {0} »link thread : " + linklapak + " {0} {0} Mohon MONEX BANK segera Teruskan Konfirmasi ini ke Penjual, Untuk memproses Barang/Jasa sesuai kesepakatan"+Environment.NewLine;
```

and still not working even though i followed [microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) tutorial :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a carriage return, too:

```
\n\r
```

instead of a simple

```
\n
That is, your statement should look like this:
string teksnya = "Payment Statement\n\rSudah " + metode + " Ke Rekening " + RekeningRekber + " MONEX BANK a.n IMANULLAH\n\r » Harga Barang/Jasa " + hargabarang + " Jasa " + lintascabank+" \n\r » Total biaya transfer : " + totalpembayaran + " \n\r » Untuk Pembelian : " + pembelian + " \n\r » Keterangan Barang/Jasa : " + keterangan + " \n\r » ID KASKUS Pembeli : " + idbuyer + " \t Email pembeli : " + emailbuyer + " \n\r » Hp Pembeli : " + nomorhandphonebuyer + " \n\r ======================================================== \n\r » BANK Penjual : " + bankseller + " \n\r » ID KASKUS Penjual : " + idseller + " \n\r » Email Penjual : " + emailseller + " \t No Hp : " + nomorhandphoneseller + " \n\r »link thread : " + linklapak + " \n\r \n\r Mohon MONEX BANK segera Teruskan Konfirmasi ini ke Penjual, Untuk memproses Barang/Jasa sesuai kesepakatan";
```

**ANYWAY**, I would use [string.Format()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) instead of concatenating so many strings.

**LATER EDIT:**
I agree that Environment.NewLine is better. Still you should use string.Format and even take advantage of the possiblility to use fields to specify fixed widths. Check the [{index[,length][:formatString]}](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx) specification.

***Ok, this is your final code:***

```
    string teksnya = string.Format("Payment Statement{0}Sudah {1} Ke Rekening {2} MONEX BANK a.n IMANULLAH{0} » Harga Barang/Jasa {3} Jasa {4} {0} » Total biaya transfer : {5} {0} » Untuk Pembelian : {6} {0} » Keterangan Barang/Jasa : {7} {0} » ID KASKUS Pembeli : {8} \t Email pembeli : {9} {0} » Hp Pembeli : {10} {0} ======================================================== {0} » BANK Penjual : {11} {0} » ID KASKUS Penjual : {12} {0} » Email Penjual : {13} \t No Hp : {14} {0} »link thread : {15} {0} {0} Mohon MONEX BANK segera Teruskan Konfirmasi ini ke Penjual, Untuk memproses Barang/Jasa sesuai kesepakatan",
        Environment.NewLine
        , metode
        , RekeningRekber
        , hargabarang
        , lintascabank
        , totalpembayaran
        , pembelian
        , keterangan
        , idbuyer
        , emailbuyer
        , nomorhandphonebuyer
        , bankseller
        , idseller
        , emailseller
        , nomorhandphoneseller
        , linklapak);
```

Comment: Even better: using a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) and its [AppendFormat()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdekwk0b.aspx) method.

Comment: @Filburt, yes this is a good approach too, but personally I prefer string.Format because it is a single method call. And for the long list of params, I put one parameter per line. This way, the format string cand easily and consistently be changed as well as the params list is as readable as calling 10 times AppendFormat. Shortly, this is easier to maintain the code and fine tune the resulting string.

Comment: check out the code I prepared for you, not tested, but should work fine

Answer (score 2):

Please use [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) instead of using `"\n"` or `"\r\n"` because the newline character is platform-dependent. Using `Environment.NewLine` makes sure that your program can also work on Linux or other platforms (with mono).

Comment: its not work, here is my code `string teksnya = ("THESTATEMENT".Environtment.NewLine);`

Comment: you should write: string teksnya = "THESTATEMENT" + Environtment.NewLine;

Comment: @Cignitor I am not sure how you came up with that code in your comment, but you ought to use `+` to concatenate strings.

Comment: yeah, and how do i make my string into the same format as the first picture ?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used `\r` or `\n\r` in years.

I prefer `Environment.NewLine`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Replace "\n" with "\r\n" for correct linebreaks.